# BaseX database: How to specify namespace context for query using xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces, basex

I am using BaseX 8.2.3 and need to query XML-documents with a default namespace. I know you have to specify the namespace context in this case. How do I do this in the BaseX GUI (I type my query in the "Find" field).

BTW I am also aware of the clark notation. However, my documents are fairly complex (and large) and i am looking for a (far more) compact syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the BaseX wiki](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Graphical_User_Interface), the input bar has an XQuery mode as an alternative to the Find mode. So you can use XQuery to declare namespace prefixes and then use them in your XPath expressions. E.g.

```
declare namespace xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
//xh:p
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this with BaseX. It's just the result of online research. If it gives an error message, let me know what it says and maybe I can help.

Comment: Good tip, works via XQuery button only! The whole query must be a one-liner. Minor disadvantage is that code completion does not work anymore.